# Kotlin loses nullability information when removing redudant SAM constructor from java

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-java-interop

I'm using SendBird in one of my project. One of the function is used to connect to the sdk:

```
SendBird.connect(id, token, object : SendBird.ConnectHandler {
    override fun onConnected(user: User?, e: SendBirdException?) {
        if (e != null) {
            // handle error
        } else {
            // handle success
        }
    }
})
```

Kotlin hints me that I can convert this to a lambda:

```
SendBird.connect(userId.toString(), accessToken) { user, e ->
    if (e != null) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        // handle success
    }
}
```

The issue is that inside the lambda `user` is of type `User!` while the real type is `User?` which sometime leads to crash.

The SendBird android sdk is written in java and nothing is annotated properly with `@Nullable`/`@NonNull`. Any way to use the lambda while keeping the nullable type `User?`?

Comment: Have you tried specifying type explicitly and nullability in the argument `user : User?, e : Throwable -> ` ?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I'm way too dumb sometimes... Thanks! I'll mark the answer from Sinner as good since it's the same. It should be inferred by kotlin though.

Comment: *It should be inferred by kotlin though* -- How can it be inferred by Kotlin if, as you said, this is specified without nullability information in Java? Platform types are here for convenience, because using non-null java APIs would be really annoying if Kotlin just considered every Java type as nullable.

Comment: Not annotated should be considered as nullable.

Comment: @Benjamin It used to be (long ago), but the users were unhappy, so platform types were introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

specify the type explicitly

```
SendBird.connect(userId.toString(), accessToken) { user: User?, e ->
    if (e != null) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        // handle success
    }
}
```